# Issue with @ngrx/store and switch statements within reducers

Tags: ngrx

I have the following **two** @ngrx/store reducers:

```
import {ActionReducer, Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import {UserAccount} from '../shared/models/useraccount.model';

export const SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT = 'SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT';
export const UPDATE_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT_FIRST_NAME = 'UPDATE_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT_FIRST_NAME';

export const currentUserAccountReducer: ActionReducer<UserAccount> = (state: UserAccount, action: Action) => {

  console.log('currentUserAccountReducer:', state, action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT: {
      return action.payload;
    }
    case UPDATE_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT_FIRST_NAME: {
      state.firstName = action.payload;
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export const SET_AUTHENTICATED = 'SET_AUTHENTICATED';
export const SET_UNAUTHENTICATED = 'SET_UNAUTHENTICATED';

export const authenticatedReducer: ActionReducer<boolean> = (state: boolean, action: Action) => {

  console.log('authenticatedReducer:', state, action);

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_AUTHENTICATED: {
      return true;
    }
    case SET_UNAUTHENTICATED: {
      return false;
    }
  }
};
```

However, for some reason when I issue a dispatch for the 1st reducer (i.e. `currentUserAccountReducer`) then it changes the state for the 2rd reducer (i.e. `authenticatedReducer`)...

Here is the dispatch causing this issue:

```
this.store.dispatch({type: SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT, payload: currentUserAccount});
```

Here is how I initialize the store in the `imports` section:

```
StoreModule.provideStore(
 {
   currentUserAccount: currentUserAccountReducer,
   authenticated: authenticatedReducer
 })
```

Can someone please provide advice?

**edit**: The issue is that `authenticated` ends up `undefined`!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `switch` statements in your reducers do not contain `default` cases. You need to add `default` cases that return the `state`, as the reducers will be called for **all** actions - the store has no way of knowing which reducer should be called for a particular action type, so each dispatched action is passed to every reducer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what you mean by *as the reducers will be called for all actions*?

Comment: Do you mean all action types?